# arrow key via stdin

Tags: bash, stdin, tty, pty

I'm trying to send an arrow key via the stdin to the bash:

cat | /bin/bash

then i am typing "echo hi" => "hi" appears on the console (of course without the quotes)
then i press the arrow key up => ^[[A command not found appears

Is it possible to send an arrow key to an program via the stdin ?

The reason why i am asking is: I want to control the bash from another programm. I would like to send arrow keys to the bash

Comment: Why do you want to send arrow keys to bash? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to control a bash via a web interface. Therefore i have to be able to send such keys to the bash (e.g. opening and editing in a vi).

Comment: I realize that's just an example, but you don't need to use arrow keys in vi; that's what i, j, k, and l are for.

Answer (score 5):

What you really should be doing is create a pseudo-tty device (using `openpty()` or similar), start `bash` on that PTY, and send your key strokes through that PTY device.  See [the section on “Pseudo-Terminals”](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pseudo_002dTerminals.html) in the GNU C Library Manual.

Comment: Yes, then after that make four chars containing the ASCII values of the arrow keys and write them to the master side of the pty with 
" write( MasterPTY_FD, CharContainingSomeArrowKey, sizeof(CharContainingSomeArrowKey ) " The hex code to assign to the char for the up arrow is 0x18. Down is: 0x19. Left is: 0x1B. Right is: 0x1A

Answer (score 0):

Try starting bash with the `-i` switch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cat`. Use the Bash builtin `read` command with the `-e` option to enable readline support.

```
# version 1
while IFS="" read -r -e -d $'\n' line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done | /bin/bash

# version 2
#set -o pipefail
# kill 0: kill process group
(
while IFS="" read -r -e -d $'\n' line; do 
   #trap 'trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; kill $PPID' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR 
   trap 'trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; kill 0' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR 
   printf '%s\n' "$line" >> ~/.bash_history
   history -n
   printf '%s\n' "$line" 
done 
) | (trap 'trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; kill 0' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; /bin/bash)
#) | (trap 'trap - EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; kill $PPID' EXIT HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM ERR; /bin/bash)
```